# Multiple pages in an Excel file using Java POI

Tags: excel, apache, apache-poi

Can we create multiple pages in an excel file using Java, if possible using [Apache POI library](http://poi.apache.org/)? I tried googling it, but it returns how we can create multiple sheets. However, we are looking for multiple pages in the excel sheet.

Thanks,
Masum

Comment: Can you clarify what you need to accomplish? It sounds like you are trying to set page breaks, do you want the sheet to print on a particular size paper?

Comment: @Dave, Yes, you are right. I am trying to achieve page break so that each page contains header and footer information. For printing purpose, you can consider A4 size.